# Creating clip in processing script for layers in directory

Tags: qgis, postgis, layers, clip, batch

I am trying to create a simple script for me to clip the layers of a directory. The moment I create an output directory it no longer creates the interface of the tool. Additionally, I'm not sure I have the clip parameters well created.

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsField, QgsFeature, QgsFeatureSink,
QgsFeatureRequest, QgsProcessing, QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource, QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
QgsProcessingParameterNumber)
import processing

class clip_dir (QgsProcessingAlgorithm):     
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    INPUT_CLIP = 'CLIP'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def name(self):
        return "Clip de capas"

    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("clipeado", text)

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr("CLIP Geoinnova")

    def group(self):
        return self.tr("clip_capa")

    def groupId(self):
        return "example"

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("This process generate un clip with one output and one input")

    def helpUrl(self):
        return "https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingAlgorithm.html"

    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()
    
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
            self.INPUT,
            self.tr("Input layer (Required)"),
            [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource( 
            self.INPUT_CLIP, 
            self.tr("Clip layer (Required)"), 
            [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination(
            self.OUTPUT,
            self.tr("folder")))
            
    #def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        #layer_input = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
        #layer_clip = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT_CLIP, context)
        #folder = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context)
        
        #processing.run("qgis:clip", {
                            'INPUT': parameters['INPUT'],
                            'OVERLAY': parameters['INPUT_CLIP'],
                            'OUTPUT': parameters['OUTPUT']
                        })
        #return {'OUTPUT': parameters['OUTPUT']}
```

Comment: Are you trying to clip multiple layers with a single clip layer, and then save multiple layers into the output folder? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to clip to raster with a shape (polygon)

import os
import gdal

```
input_path = r"D:\GIS_StackChange\input"#folder whit raster file
out = "D:\GIS_StackChange\output"
area_shape =r"D:\GIS_StackChange\input\Area_work.shp"

bandList = [band for band in os.listdir(input_path) if band[-4:]=='.TIF']

iter = range(len(bandList))

for i in iter:
    clip_imag = gdal.Warp(srcDSOrSrcDSTab = input + '\\'+ bandList[i],
                        destNameOrDestDS=out+'\\'+'clip'+bandList[i],
                        cutlineDSName = area_shape,
                        cropToCutline=True,
                        dstSRS="EPSG:3795",
                        outputType=gdal.GDT_Float32)
```